# Rails - how to make global object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, global-variables, application-variables

I want to parse a XML document once - at Rails application startup.
It is parsed to an object, and I want this object to be accessible from anywhere, from any user session.
How to implement this application-level object the right way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: Where to define global constants?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110866/ruby-on-rails-where-to-define-global-constants)

Comment: May be, but there are small constants defined. Is this approach applicable to a large object?

Comment: I would like to have MyApp::Application.GLOBAL_OBJECT

Comment: I think you should do it somewhere within initializers in config folder.

Comment: I'm asking not about where to DO it, but where to PUT the result of doing.

Comment: For example, I created a "/config/initializers/init_xml_data.rb" where is one line defined "MY_DATA = MyXmlReference.new", but one of controllers complains about "uninitialized constant TheController::MY_DATA"

Comment: Why not use a singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need information from the xml and you can have it as simple hashes/arrays/strings, and no specific object is necessary, you could use [Settingslogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic) for this - normally it takes yaml file and then is accessible throughout the whole application. For example, you define a class:

```
# app/models/settings.rb
class Settings < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/application.yml"
  namespace Rails.env
end

# config/application.yml
defaults: &defaults
  global: 'Hello'

development:
  <<: *defaults
  more:
    data: [1, 2, 3]
```

And then you can use it anywhere like this:

```
> Settings.global
=> "Hello"
> Settings.more.data
=> [1, 2, 3]
```