# Where should I store constant data and then how to reference it in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a array of data, for example times (7:00am, 7:30am, etc.), that I want stored and referenced in a couple places.

1) Where should I store this data? I was originally thinking in my DB (I'm using mongoid) but I'm not sure if that's over kill.

2) How would I go about referencing it? Let's say, from a drop down menu.

Comment: is it supposed to change very often?

Comment: We use the strategy defined here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110866/ruby-on-rails-where-to-define-global-constants

Comment: @simonmorley I agree it's the way to proceed if constants are not shared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this kind of situation, I create a `Constants` module in lib:

```
module Constants
  SCHEDULER_STEPS = %w( 7:00am 7:30am )
end
```

Then I access it wherever I need with:

```
Constants::SCHEDULER_STEPS
```

Note: be sure to add `libs` to your autoload path in the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I ended up creating a "global_constants.rb" file in "/config/initializers". The code I used was: http://d.pr/n/CMCW and used ":collection => Constants::BUSINESS_HOURS" in the select box to call the array. You way seems very similar, do you know of any benefit doing it your way?

Comment: I think yaml is overkill for your needs. Having constant defined in the class where it's used is the way to go if it's not shared, but you actually told it's "referenced in a couple of places".

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation and please excuse the newbness.

Comment: It's better to ask questions than remain with doubts, there are no stupid questions :)

Comment: actually you did exactly what I told you, you just changed the path :)

Comment: I won't add too much info in initializers, actually, I only add there what is needed for Rails startup. Your constant module is not among those. Let `autoload` do it's job and avoid clutering your memory too soon, you'll gain boot time in the long run

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to put this sort of data on the model it's most closely related to. For example, if the times in your example were the times to run a backup, put them in the `Backup` model with the rest of the behavior related to backups:

```
# app/models/backup.rb
class Backup < ActiveRecord::Base
  AVAILABLE_RUN_TIMES = %w{7:00am 7:30am ...}

  def run_at=(date)
    BackupSchedule.create(self, date)
  end
end

# app/views/backups/_form.html.erb
<%= select_tag(:run_at, options_for_select(Backup::AVAILABLE_RUN_TIMES)) %>
```

I've used the "big bucket of constants" approach too, but I would only use it if there's truly no more relevant place for the constants to live.

Answer (score 2):

For such kind of requirements i prefer

**1st)** create a `config/app_constants.yml`

Code here

```
production:
  time_list: "'7:00am','7:30am','7:40am'"
test:
  time_list: "'7:00am','7:30am','7:40am'"
development:
  time_list: "'7:00am','7:30am','7:40am'"
```

**2nd** Create under `lib/app_constant.rb`

```
module AppConstant
  extend self

  CONFIG_FILE = File.expand_path('../config/app_constants.yml', __FILE__)
  @@app_constants = YAML.load(File.read(CONFIG_FILE))
  @@constants = @@app_constants[Rails.env]

  def get_time_list
    @@constants['time_list'].split(',')
  end
end
```

**3rd** Call it anywhere like

```
AppConstant.get_time_list #will return an array
```

With this you just have to make changes at a single clean place(`app_constants.yml`) and will reflect throughout you application wherever `AppConstant.get_time_list` is used

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating a "global_constants.rb" file in "/config/initializers" with the following code:

```
module Constants
    BUSINESS_HOURS = ["6:00am","6:15am","6:30am","6:45am","7:00am"]
end
```

Then I called the data with `Constants::BUSINESS_HOURS`, specifically for the select box, the code was: `<%= f.input :hrs_op_sun_open, :collection => Constants::BUSINESS_HOURS %>`

Many of the answers here seem viable and I suspect they are all correct ways of doing what I needed.

Comment: Don't add useless initializers, this will slow your boot time. In this   case, you should leverage the autoload and keep the file in `/lib`

Comment: Interesting. I moved the file into "/lib" and added "config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)" to my "config/application.rb" file (inside of the Application class), restarted my server and it isn't working. Any idea what step I'm missing?

Comment: BTW, the error I am getting is "uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Constants"

Comment: Replace `config.root` with `Rails.root`

Comment: Nice, it worked. I also had to rename the file form "global_constants.rb" to "constants.rb". Thanks again for the help.