# Globally accessible class that connects to the db during startup only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a globally accessible class in my Rails project that will contain some active record result sets also.

```
@settings = Settings.first
@locales = Locales.all
$websiteSettings = WebsiteSettings.new(@settings, @locales)
```

Where should I be creating this class, is an initializer the best place?

I want to be able to access this class inside my controllers and views.

I understand that if the data changes in the database I will have to restart my rails application or update these global instances.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in an initializer and set it as a [global constant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4110969/1143732):

```
#config/initializers/settings.rb
module Settings
  @settings = Settings.first
  @locales  = Locales.all
  WEBSITE   = WebsiteSettings.new(@settings, @locales)
end
```

This would allow you to access `Settings::WEBSITE` throughout your app.

This is only applicable if you're calling the data through `ActiveRecord`.

---

If you weren't accessing the data through the db, you'd be better using one of the many [`settings`](https://github.com/railsconfig/config) gems, or adding the settings directly to the [`Rails.config` class](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/configuring.html#custom-configuration):

```
#config/application.rb
config.settings.title = "Test"  #-> Rails.configuration.settings.title
```

--

As an aside, I would strongly recommend you refactor your code; you're making 3 db calls to get a series of settings for your app.

Surely you could put all the settings inside the `Settings` model, scoped around different locales:

```
#config/initializers/settings.rb
module Settings
  SETTINGS = Settings.where(locale: :en)
end
```