# How to access one variable across the page in ruby?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cakephp

Now I am new in ruby language. Currently learning ruby. I am expert coder in the PHP. Basically I am working in the CakePHP. CakePHP and Ruby directory structure approximately same. But I am confusing little bit in the Ruby Code.

In CakePHP while I am define any variable in `bootstrap.php` I am getting this variable across the site.

Suppose I have a variable name `$gallery_path = 'files/gallery/';` If I `echo $gallery_path` in controller, model and view. I am getting my gallery path.

But here in ruby I am unable to define any variable like php `bootstrap.php` Please suggest me.

Comment: you're looking for global variables...

Comment: @SuperPeanut No, global variables are not the answer here.

Comment: What sort of variables are you trying to define? Ruby strongly encourages people to organize these into modules or classes to simplify access and keep them from conflicting.

Comment: what Chinu is talking about in PHP is called global variable. So his question is : How can I use the global variable feature from PHP in Ruby...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: Where to define global constants?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110866/ruby-on-rails-where-to-define-global-constants)

Comment: you mean you need constants ?

Answer (score 2):

For things that change frequently enough that you need to edit them now and then, but infrequently enough that you're not constantly changing it, a simple `module` works well here.

You can start with something like this:

```
module SiteConfiguration
  mattr_accessor :site_name
  mattr_accessor :payment_provider
end
```

Then you can configure that in `config/environment.rb`:

```
SiteConfiguration.site_name = 'The Site'
SiteConfiguration.payment_provider = 'PayPal'
```

These are accessible everywhere in your app.

Comment: Can you please say me about the `module Siteconfiguration`?

Comment: I am getting error message `uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SiteConfiguration`

Comment: @Chinu You need to put `site_configuration.rb` somewhere that's auto-loaded. `app/concerns` is one place that's usually checked.

Comment: Ok. Let me know how to get site name in my layout?

Comment: It's just as you would with anything: `<%= SiteConfiguration.site_name %>`.

Comment: can you please briefly describe me. I am tried but unable to do that.

Comment: Here I am using using this  `config/site_configuration.rb` I am putting this code `module SiteConfiguration
  mattr_accessor :site_name
  mattr_accessor :payment_provider
end` and `config/environment.rb` putting `SiteConfiguration.site_name = 'The Site'
SiteConfiguration.payment_provider = 'PayPal'` let me know is it right or not?

Comment: I am getting error message `uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::SiteConfiguration`

Comment: Finally i got my output. Thank you

Comment: I faced another problem `no implicit conversion of nil into String`

Comment: While I am getting `no implicit conversion of nil into String` message I restated my server then working fine. After some times I am getting same error. I mean each time I am restarting my server.

Comment: I have added one question. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564295/how-to-fix-no-implicit-conversion-of-nil-into-string-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

you can use environment variables, try this gem: `https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv`
or you can define them:

```
ENV["host"] = "localhost:3000"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean global variables. In Ruby-on-Rails you can write it like

Controller:

```
@value = 2+1
```

HTML:

```
<%= @value %>
```

So your output in your browser will be "3"

Answer (score 0):

Your `application_controller.rb` should be write below

```
$gallery_path = 'files/gallery/';
```

Your view file

```
<%=$gallery_path %>
```

Comment: This is extremely messy and should be an absolute last resort. Global variables are used very, very sparingly in Ruby.