# How to fix "no implicit conversion of nil into String" in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing one small web application in my local machine. I want to set my some common information globally.
Here is my code:

*app/controllers/concerns/site_configuration.rb*

```
module SiteConfiguration
  mattr_accessor :site_name
  mattr_accessor :banner_path
  mattr_accessor :avatar_path  
  mattr_accessor :gallery_path  
  mattr_accessor :category_path  
end
```

*config/environment.rb*

```
SiteConfiguration.site_name = 'Site Name Here'
SiteConfiguration.banner_path = 'uploads/banners/'
SiteConfiguration.avatar_path = 'uploads/avatar/'
SiteConfiguration.gallery_path = 'uploads/gallery/'
SiteConfiguration.category_path = 'uploads/category/'
```

*app/views/galleries/index.html.erb*

```
<img src="<%=root_path+SiteConfiguration.gallery_path+@gallery.image %>" alt="" />
```

**Here is I am getting error message**

> TypeError in Galleries#index
>
> Showing D:/xxx/project/app/views/galleries/index.html.erb where line #1 raised:
>
> no implicit conversion of nil into String

Above code working fine. But one big problem is whatever changes I made every time there is a need to restart the server.

If I restart server then its working fine. After few min if need any changes I am getting same error message. Let me know what is the problem there?

Comment: Just don't send nil variables to your erb, check it before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lazy evaluation to string:

```
<img src="<%= "#{root_path}#{SiteConfiguration.gallery_path}#{@gallery.image}" %>" alt="" />
```

but be better to make sure, why exactly one of the field becomes `nil`? Also move the code to helper or decorator.

To make configuration customizable use [`config`](https://github.com/railsconfig/config) gem. So you will have just a YML-file:

**config/settings.yml**:

```
---
site_name: 'Site Name Here'
banner_path: 'uploads/banners/'
avatar_path: 'uploads/avatar/'
gallery_path: 'uploads/gallery/'
category_path: 'uploads/category/'
```

So here you have to use `Settings` constant instead of `SiteConfiguration`:

```
<img src="<%= "#{root_path}#{Settings.gallery_path}#{@gallery.image}" %>" alt="" />
```

Comment: missing `SiteConfiguration.gallery_path` in my image path. Please check `<img  alt="Dsc 0380" src="/DSC_0380.jpg">`

Comment: My Image path should be- `<img alt="Dsc 0380" src="/uploads/gallery/DSC_0380.jpg">`

Comment: I saw you updated answer. Let me know how to print my `settings.yml` `gallery_path` in my view(erb) file?

Comment: Yes I just generate config file. Now working fine. No need `SiteConfiguration` Thank you dear.