# Where to Put Global Constant in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, initialization

I want to define Global Constant in Rails 3 but I am confuse looking so many differnet answer on Google.

I was trying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856737/where-how-to-code-constants-in-rails-3-application/5814314#5814314) but it did not work and gave error:

```
Undefined method `music_type' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0xb7ac0230>
```

In /config/application.rb

```
module RailsRoot
 Class Application < Rails :: Application
 config.music_type = '2'
 end
end
```

In Controller

```
RailsRoot::Application::config.music_type
```

not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: It working...I forgot to restart the server

Answer (score 1):

you need a dedicated gem for that, smth like http://rubygems.org/gems/rails-3-settings

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450285/how-to-define-custom-configuration-variables-in-rails) thread has a detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

I think, the best way is to define you own initializer in `config/initializers/` folder.

Example:

Create `my_initializer.rb` in `config/initializers/` folder with following content:

```
require 'socket'

def local_ip
  orig, Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup, true # turn off      reverse DNS resolution temporarily

  UDPSocket.open do |s|
    s.connect '64.233.187.99', 1
    s.addr.last
  end
ensure
  Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = orig
end

SERVER_IP = local_ip
```

and in some controller use that constant:

```
log_it "Server IP address is: #{SERVER_IP}"
```